# JAXB-REST cannot get extended class object

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy

I am having class A and class B
class B extends class A

It will be like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@XmlSeeAlso(value={B.class})
class A implements Serializable{
  @Column(name="name")
  @XmlAttribute(name="name")
  private String name;

    //more fields and getters and setters...

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
class B extends A{

    @XmlElement(name="type")
    private String type;

    // Fields and getter setters...
}
```

When I pass B class object in REST POST method I cannot get instance of B instead I only get instance of class A. How can I get B instance, Is there any more configuration to do this? 
Since I have more class like B which all are extends class A, I need to persist respective Entity in DB. Please help me on this.

**EDIT:**

my input would like this:

```
<root name="Duster">
    <type>SUV<type>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you show the POST method?

Comment: Seems to be a conflict with with the same `@XmlRootElement` annotation value. You can get rid of it on the subclass and it will still work

Comment: @peeskillet so It will not detect the instance based on input values? Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe some JAXB expert will come along and answer this for you :-). I was just providing a comment based on what I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
@DiscriminatorColumn  
(  
 name="Discriminator",  
 discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING  
)  
@DiscriminatorValue(value="B")
```

Annotations we can do it.